# Retrieve foreground time spent by an app from 12AM to current time using UsageStatsManager

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

I want to find out the foreground time of a certain app from 12AM to the current time . Here is what i tried so far

```
    String PackageName = "Nothing";
    long TimeInforground = 500;
    UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService("usagestats");

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats( UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_BEST,
                                                                 c.getTimeInMillis(),
                                                                 time );
    if ( stats != null )
    {
        for ( UsageStats usageStats : stats )
        {
            if ( usageStats.getPackageName().contains("example.app") )
            {
                TimeInforground = usageStats.getTotalTimeInForeground();

                PackageName = usageStats.getPackageName();

                minutes = (int) ((TimeInforground / (1000 * 60)) % 60);

                seconds = (int) (TimeInforground / 1000) % 60;

                hours = (int) ((TimeInforground / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

                Log.e("BAC", "PackageName is" + PackageName + "Time is: " + hours + "h" + ":" + minutes + "m" + seconds + "s");

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the foreground time to be 0 when the time is a little more than 12 AM and the example.app is not opened. But that doesn't seem to be the case. It tends to not reset at 12 AM but much later.

I haven't found too much  documentation on UsageStatsManager and the above code is a slight modification of an other answer on StackOverflow to match my needs .

I have also tried UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY but even that doesn't seem to be serving my purpose exactly.

Any help is much Appreciated.

Comment: How much later does it rest?

Comment: Hey . It seems to be random . I am not really able to figure out a pattern . But its generally after 3-5 hours that it resets